# Use custom inheritor from the hateoas.CollectionModel in hateoas.server.RepresentationModelProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, hateoas

I have simple RestController that return CollectionModel:

```
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> index() {
        List<DemoEntity> all = Arrays.asList(new DemoEntity(1L, "first"),
                                            new DemoEntity(2L, "second"),
                                            new DemoEntity(3L, "third"));
        List<EntityModel<DemoEntity>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        all.forEach(demoEntity -> list.add(new EntityModel<>(demoEntity)));
        CollectionModel<EntityModel<DemoEntity>> collectionModel = new CollectionModel<>(list);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(collectionModel);
    }
```

DemoEntity has only two fields, id and name. SecondEntity is the same.
I am trying to use RepresentationModelProcessor:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDataRestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<DemoEntity>> demoEntityProcessor() {
        return new RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<DemoEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public EntityModel<DemoEntity> process(EntityModel<DemoEntity> entity) {
                return new MyHateoasEntityModel<>(entity.getContent(), entity.getLink("self").orElse(new Link("self")));
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RepresentationModelProcessor<CollectionModel<EntityModel<DemoEntity>>> demoEntitiesProcessor() {

        return new RepresentationModelProcessor<CollectionModel<EntityModel<DemoEntity>>>() {

            @Override
            public CollectionModel<EntityModel<DemoEntity>> process(CollectionModel<EntityModel<DemoEntity>> collection) {
//                return new CollectionModel<>(collection.getContent());
                return new MyHateoasCollectionModel<>(collection.getContent());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<SecondEntity>> secondEntityProcessor() {
        return new RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<SecondEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public EntityModel<SecondEntity> process(EntityModel<SecondEntity> entity) {
                return new MyHateoasEntityModel<>(entity.getContent(), entity.getLink("self").orElse(new Link("self")));
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RepresentationModelProcessor<CollectionModel<EntityModel<SecondEntity>>> secondEntitiesProcessor() {

        return new RepresentationModelProcessor<CollectionModel<EntityModel<SecondEntity>>>() {

            @Override
            public CollectionModel<EntityModel<SecondEntity>> process(CollectionModel<EntityModel<SecondEntity>> collection) {
//                return new CollectionModel<>(collection.getContent());
                return new MyHateoasCollectionModel<>(collection.getContent());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

One thing here is that I want to use my own classes MyHateoasEntityModel and MyHateoasCollectionModel. They are quite simple:

```
public class MyHateoasEntityModel<T> extends EntityModel<T> {
    private T entity;

    public MyHateoasEntityModel(T entity, Iterable<Link> links) {
        super(entity, Collections.emptyList());
        this.entity = entity;
    }
    public MyHateoasEntityModel(T entity, Link... links) {
        this(entity, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

```
public class MyHateoasCollectionModel<T> extends CollectionModel<T> {
    public MyHateoasCollectionModel(Iterable<T> content, Link... links) {
        super(content, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

The question is that when the controller is called, the demoEntityProcessor, demoEntitiesProcessor methods are called in turn. And this is what i want from the application. But then, somehow, secondEntitiesProcessor is called, but shouldn't.

Earlier, spring boot 1.5.17 was used, and everything works fine.

All code on: https://github.com/KarinaPleskach/Hateoas